# Copying manually directories and folders in Java

Tags: java, directory

My task is to manually copy directories and folders from source to destination. My problem is that if user enters for source for example `C:\\folder1` and for destination `C:\\folderK` (lets assume that we have this situation)-->(see below).

```
C:\
 folder1
    B.txt
    folder2
       A.txt



C:\
    folderK
```

I want that my result is:

```
C:\
 folderK
     folder1
       B.txt
       folder2
          A.txt
```

---

And if user enters something like this for source: `C\\folder1` and for destination `C:\\folderK\\folderD` then result must be:

```
C:\
     folderK
         folderD   !!!(name of folder1 is changed to folderD)
           B.txt
           folder2
              A.txt
```

---

this is my code so far:

---

```
void copy(File source, File destination) throws IOException {

            if(source.isDirectory()){
                if(!destination.exists()){
                   destination.mkdir();
                }

                for (String file : source.list()) {
                   System.out.println(file);
                   copy(new File(source, file), new File(destination, file));
                }
            } else {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source)), "UTF-8"));
                    Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination)), "UTF-8"));

                    while(true) {
                    String line = br.readLine(); if(line == null) break;
                    bw.write(line);
                    }

                    br.close();
                    bw.close();
            }       
}
```

---

My code does not work as it is show above. It does the next thing:

```
C:\
  folderK
    B.txt
    folder2
      A.txt
```

---

What should I add in my code so it works as it should (as said in beginning)

Comment: ok we have the code, waht's your question?

Comment: My code does not work as it should. I will edit my post so you can see how my is working

Comment: What it is should does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add a boolean parameter to indicate if the last source folder has to be created in the destination, something like that:

```
void copy(File source, File destination, boolean folderCreate) throws IOException {
        if(source.isDirectory()){
            File dest;
            if(folderCreate)
                dest=new File(destination,source.getName());
            else
                dest=destination;

            if(!dest.exists()){
               dest.mkdir();
            }

            for (String file : source.list()) {
               System.out.println(file);
               copy(new File(source, file), new File(dest, file), false);
            }
        } else {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source)), "UTF-8"));
                Writer bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination)), "UTF-8"));

                while(true) {
                String line = br.readLine(); if(line == null) break;
                bw.write(line);
                }

                br.close();
                bw.close();
        }       
}
```

Comment: After you can implement other methods to automatically determine the boolean value (for exemple: folderCreate = the source folder has a parent folder)

Comment: Thank you! Only one question remains..how can I rename source to folder2 and continue to copy everything else normal if for destination user enters C:\\folder1\\folder2 (folder2 does not exist)